# The common practice to share file for all users on the same machine?

Tags: directory-structure, file-sharing

There is a server with several users.

A user may want to read another user's files (few gigabytes) and may want to put processed files in other's directory.

What's the common practice to do it? I can think of create a /share folder and make it rwx to all. Is this the common practice?

Comment: You need to define "accessible" in more details.  Does `/tmp` serve your purpose?

Comment: By access, do you mean read access, or read access + write access? Or something else?

Comment: An [answer on Askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/313332) recommends creating a directory under `/home/share` and details several ways to enable more or less writing permissions to files under that directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are searching for /usr/local/share/ but it is hard to answer since this depends on what kind of file your are planning to "share" between users.

But if we are talking about office files or something like that maybe you should use use some kind of revision system like subversion or git. And then the users will have a checkout/clone in their homedir.

---

*Update:* A way to make this a little bit better could would be that every user gets it's own subdir in the shared folder. He is allowed to write in his own folder but not the other subfolders. And all users are allowed to read from all the directories. That way you don't have to think about file collisions if two users use the same filename, or deletes the colleges files by mistake.

Btw the idea behind /usr/ is described in the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard ( http://www.pathname.com/fhs/2.2/fhs-4.1.html )

-"*/usr is shareable, read-only data.*"

So I would probably use a dir in either /home/ or /var/ instead...

Comment: I think `/usr/share/` and `/usr/local/share` are commonly used to store files shared between software packages, not users.

Comment: /usr/share is for files provided by the package manager, /usr/local/ is for files related to some application not handled by the package manager. But you should not put office document in there or something like that... But this question is quite vague on what files he plan to share.

Comment: I concur. It's hard to give a useful answer until the question makes sense.

Comment: No, `/usr/share` or `/usr/local/share` are unrelated to sharing between *users*. They're part of the system installation; `share` here means that the files can be shared between multiple architectures, on networks with heterogeneous hardware. Under Linux `/usr` is for files under the package manager's control and `/usr/local` is under the control of the system administrator.

Answer (score 3):

For occasional use, the common practice is that each user creates files in their own home directory. `~/pub` is a common name of a directory for files all other users are supposed to be able access. If only a subset of users may access certain files, use [groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_%28computing%29) or [access control lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list) to manage permissions.

For more advanced use, when multiple users may work on the same file, use a [version control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control). There's no really standard place to store the (master) repository; I've seen repositories under `~someuser/$project`, `/net/repositories/$project`, `/srv/repositories/$project`, `/var/www/$project`, `/home/$project`, etc.